# Qt: Child widgets are not enabled when their parent gets enabled

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget

I have been using Qt (more precisely Qt 5.8) for some while and have never had issues with enabling/disabling of widgets. However, I've just ran into a widget, which does not enable/disable its child widgets at all.

The following assertion is failing in my code:
`Q_ASSERT(m_ui->childWidget->isEnabledTo(m_ui->parentWidget));`,
provided that both exist AND `parentWidget` is the actual parent of `childWidget`. Also, in case specifics are needed, `childWidget` is of type `QCheckBox` and `parentWidget` is of type `QFrame`.

Of course, I can always traverse the entire tree of widgets and enable them by hand, but from what I've read in the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop), enabling/disabling of child widgets should happen automatically.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Bobby

Comment: Are you sure it is a child? Maybe you forgot to set the parent when you created the child.

Comment: @drescherjm , positive. I created everything in an UI file and also checked in the source code.

Comment: Has the child widget been explicitly disabled? If so then isEnabledTo will return false I believe.

Comment: @Serguei it is set to `disabled` in the .ui file because I've set its parent to `disabled`. Don't know if that counts as explicit disabling :)

Comment: @BoyanVushkov explicitly disabling would require calling setEnabled on the widget itself. Could you post the relevant code generated by designer?

Comment: @Serguei , I just checked for explicit calls to setEnabled in the designer-generated code - still nothing.